# Asp.net Core model binder accepts random integer for boolean types

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding

Given the model has a boolean property:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsMale { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to POST the following payload:

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "isMale": 12345 // any random integer
}
```

To a simple action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        return Ok();
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

The `person.IsMale` property gets the value of `true`.

If passing `isMale: "foobar"` i get an invalid type error

If passing `isMale: "0"` i get an invalid type error

If passing `isMale: "1"` i get an invalid type error

If passing `isMale: "True"` i get `true`

If passing `isMale: "False"` i get `false`

If passing `isMale: 0` i get `false`

If passing `isMale: 1` i get `true`

If passing `isMale: 34` (a random int) i get `true`

### Question:

Why it considers that a random integer defaults to `true` and how to change that behaviour to complain that the type passed in is inappropriate (int instead of bool)?

Comment: 0 and 1 are obviously considered as boolean values. However, I am also very curious about how to prevent 0 and 1 to be cast as bool values.

Comment: @Skrface I know that in the traditional web api / mvc you'd have to write custom model binders for casting from int to bool, or string to bool. I really don't get why  a random number is considered `true`. Looks like a hack for avoiding extra overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your examples, any numeric value that is not `0` is interpreted as `true` which is not strange at all.

The quoted versions `"0"` and `"1"` are `string` types and cannot directly be parsed to `bool`.

See the documentation for [`bool.Parse(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.parse?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on why treating non zero as false is a good idea. (i'm looking at it from a contracts definition/validation perspective)

Comment: The `bool` type is just syntactic sugar for a single bit which can be either `0` eg `false`, or `1` eg `true`. You are not treating non-zero as `false`, you're treating it as `true` because it has a value higher than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not a perfect solution, but once you send JSON as a request body, such workaround should fit your needs:

```
public class Person
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isMale")]
    public string IsMaleString { private get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsMale
    {
      get
      {
        return bool.TryParse(IsMaleString, out bool value)
          ? value
          : IsMaleString == "1";
      }
    }
  }
```

In case of variations of 'true' and '1' it'll return 'true', otherwise it'll be 'false'